# namespace std overloading less than

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, std

I was curious about why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::tuple<int, std::string> intString;
bool operator<(intString& lhs, intString& rhs){
    return std::tie(std::get<1>(lhs), std::get<0>(lhs)) < std::tie(std::get<1>(rhs), std::get<0>(rhs));
}

void printIntStrings(std::vector<intString>& v){
    for (intString& i : v){
        std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << " is " << std::get<1>(i) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<intString> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_tuple(5, "five"));
    v.push_back(std::make_tuple(2, "two"));
    v.push_back(std::make_tuple(9, "nine"));
    printIntStrings(v);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    printIntStrings(v);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can understand, I simply create a vector of intStrings and my operator should sort by the second element in the tuple first thus the output should be (last 3 lines anyway)

```
5 five
9 nine
2 two
```

However running it on my machine I get

```
2 two
5 five
9 nine
```

which implies that the sort is using the default less than operator, ignoring the one I specified. Note, adding const before the parameters didn't seem to affect anything.

I found three ways to "fix" this.

**Fix #1**

surround bool operator< ... in namespace std like so:

```
namespace std{
    bool operator<(intString& lhs, intString& rhs){
        return std::tie(std::get<1>(lhs), std::get<0>(lhs)) < std::tie(std::get<1>(rhs), std::get<0>(rhs));
    }
}
```

However I was told we should never add things to the std namespace since that behavior is undefined, so this fix seems the worst.

**Fix #2**

Add in something custom to the tuple like so:

```
enum class TRASH{DOESNTMATTER};
typedef std::tuple<int, std::string, TRASH> intString;
bool operator<(intString& lhs, intString& rhs){
    return std::tie(std::get<1>(lhs), std::get<0>(lhs)) < std::tie(std::get<1>(rhs), std::get<0>(rhs));
}
```

(and obviously add in TRASH::DOESNTMATTER as the third make_tuple argument)
However, this seemed like a lot of work for something this simple. Also, it seems wasteful since the enum is not meaningfully used.

**Fix #3**

Use the predicate sort like so:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), operator<);
```

This seemed to be the most elegant solution. However, I don't see why I have to explicitly tell the compiler to use my defined operator<.

So I want to know:

1) why this happens? Shouldn't c++ find my implementation and use that?

2) which "fix" is the best? if none of the ones I found, what would you recommend?

Any ideas? Thanks for reading!

Comment: The standard `operator<` is a better match because its parameters are `const`.

Comment: @Oktalist Oops, forgot to mention but adding const before both parameters didn't help. will edit

Comment: The problem is because there's _already_ an `operator<` for tuples, so the compiler uses the official one rather than your hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `operator<` overload is not visible at the point where `<` is used (which is in the body of `std::sort` and/or any helper functions called by it, somewhere in `<algorithm>`).

If it is to be used, it must be picked up by argument-dependent lookup; but there's nothing in `std::tuple<int, std::string>` that has the global namespace as an associated namespace, so ADL doesn't help you, either, and the standard one is used.

Pass it as a comparator, preferably using a lambda or function object (which inlines better than function pointers), is the simplest fix. I'd also recommend renaming it; having a `operator<` overload with completely different semantics than the standard one, which may or may not be used by the expression `a < b` depending on where that expression is, is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I figured it was something like that. Would there be a way to "force" ADL to pick it up? maybe something along the lines of using namespace global (tried namespace global and it didn't work)

Comment: @BillyWon Not without changing the type. I also really do not recommend writing a `<` that does something different than the one the standard library supplies.

Comment: Thanks! Will change to a more descriptive name. Had it as overloaded < in hopes that I could use the two argument sort. Was originally compareStringsFirst

Answer (score -1):

you already fix it by your self

the problem is your operator< function doesn't override the default tuple::operator<, they are in different namespace

so, both your Fix#1 and Fix#3 are good solution

Fix#1 put them into the same namespace make it override correct,I think is the best way

Comment: And causes undefined behavior in the process. Yes, that's definitely the best way.